# Python 2 XML Etree xpath : Getting Predicate error while try to parse variable in attribute check, like [@attrib ='VAL'] but using [@attrib = '%s']

Tags: python-2.7, xml.etree

Sample XML :

```
<ParentTag TEST_ID="xxxxxx" ID="1">
    <Child TagType="Manual">
        <Manhrs Cost="100"/>
        <Testing VAL="RANDOM STRING"/>
    </Child>
    <Child TagType="Automated">
        <Manhrs Cost="10"/>
        <Testing VAL="RANDOM STRING2"/>
    </Child>
</ParentTag>
<ParentTag TEST_ID="YYYYYY" ID="1">
    <Child TagType="Manual">
        <Manhrs Cost="100"/>
        <Testing VAL="RANDOM STRING"/>
    </Child>
    <Child TagType="Automated">
        <Manhrs Cost="10"/>
        <Testing VAL="RANDOM STRING2"/>
    </Child>
</ParentTag>
<ParentTag TEST_ID="ZZZZZZZ" ID="1">
    <Child TagType="Manual">
        <Manhrs Cost="100"/>
        <Testing VAL="RANDOM STRING"/>
    </Child>
    <Child TagType="Automated">
        <Manhrs Cost="10"/>
        <Testing VAL="RANDOM STRING2"/>
    </Child>
</ParentTag>
```

so if i run:

```
TEST_ID = xxxxxx
for n in root.findall("ParentTag[@TEST_ID = '%s']//Child[@TagType = 'Automated']", % TEST_ID):
        print("FOUND")
```

ERROR: python2.7/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 224, in prepare_predicate
    raise SyntaxError("invalid predicate")
SyntaxError: invalid predicate

Please note that the above same code does work in python 3, but I need this to work in Python 2.7
If there is any alternative other than looping multiple times in python 2 kindly provide the same

Also I have to use xml.etree.ElementTree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its due to space between the attribute and value instead of with space, one should define it like this :[@TEST_ID='{}']".format(value)